# What is Locking in MySQL and when would you use it?

Tags: mysql, rdbms

What is Locking in MySQL (or any RDBMS) and when would you use it? A Layman explanation with a Example would be great!

Comment: It is a useful optimization, for concurrent users: http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/MySQL-Optimization-part-2/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We have a joint bank account with a balance of $200

I go to the ATM and put my card into the machine, the machine checks that I have a balance of $200

Meanwhile, you go into the bank and ask for $50, the teller brings up your account and confirms that you have the money.

I request a withdrawal of $200, the machine counts my money gives me $200 and sets my balance at $0

The teller counts your money and gives you the $50, the system then updates the balance on the account as $150 ($200 - $50 withdrawl).

So now we have $250 cash and $150 left in the account. $200 profit.

The database should have used locks to prevent both transactions occuring at the same time.

The problem is if you handle every transaction in that way then we would lose concurrency and performance would suffer, so there are different `transaction isolation levels` that are used depending on the scenario, for instance you might not care that someone can modify data that has been read in a transaction.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29

You should learn these and understand the scenarios where they are applicable.

Comment: Thanks @Chris Diver great explanation! I understand it now ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Locking can be crucial to avoid two users modifying data at the same time. You may think that's unlikely, but depending on the application, there is a significant risk if the same data is frequently changed by different users.

Imagine the following situation *without* using locks: John opens his screen (he doesn't know he's using a database, he is only an end user who is looking at a pretty screen), modifies some data, and then hits "Save". Let's say John open the screen at 9:30 and then saves the data at 9:32.

However, Mary opened exactly the same screen and the same record at 9:29. She saw at that time the same data that John did at 9:30. Then, she updates the record, and hits "Save" at 9:31.

What data was saved? John's or Mary's?

Mary happily keeps working on other records, and when she comes back later to open the record again, she sees that her changes were lost, and she sees John's changes instead!!

Be aware that locking has to be used wisely to prevent unexpected side-effects. For example, let's say that your program locks a record every time somebody opens it make a change. What happens if John locks the record, and leaves his session screen open to have lunch or he looses his connection? The lock can remain there, locked and unchangeable, for a long time, while prohibiting everybody else from changing (or even looking at) that record. Other consideration may be performance, because the time for the database to lock and unlock records may become noticeable for a large number of transactions.

Understanding locking is crucial to maintain happy users and data integrity. Please look at the documentation.

Comment: Versioning the data would be a better solution to the usecase you described. You can't really keep a lock for that long... What I would do is, when John hits save, read the data + version, compare them to what you displayed the user, and then do an UPDATE on the data that checks for the version you just read two minutes ago. If the version is not the same, this means someone else touched your data - you must refresh it.

Comment: @ripper234: that's why I said that locking requires multiple considerations for the best approach. You are correct for the explained scenario, and your suggestion is well taken. I did not intend, nor would be possible, to make a complete discussion of the concept here. The purpose was to provide a simple, layman's answer.

Answer (score 3):

A few days ago I answered [a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325458/which-locking-scheme-and-isolation-level-should-one-use-for-sequence-number-gener) and gave an example which demonstrates a situation where [locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(database)) allows multiple users to concurrently insert rows in a table with an incrementing `id`, without using `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Consider the following schema as an example:

```
CREATE TABLE demo_table (id int) ENGINE=INNODB;

-- // Add few rows
INSERT INTO demo_table VALUES (1), (2), (3);
```

Then we can do the following:

```
START TRANSACTION;

-- // Get the MAX(id) so that we increment it by one
SELECT @x := MAX(id) FROM your_table FOR UPDATE;

+---------------+
| @x := MAX(id) |
+---------------+
|             3 |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The [`FOR UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html) syntax is what actually puts a lock on the rows read by this query.

Without committing the transaction, we start another separate session (simulating a concurrent user), and do the same:

```
START TRANSACTION;

-- // Get the MAX(id) as well
SELECT MAX(id) FROM demo_table FOR UPDATE;
```

The database will wait until the lock set in the previous session is released before running this query.

Therefore switching to the previous session, we can insert the new row and commit the transaction:

```
-- // Insert a new row with id = MAX(id) + 1
INSERT INTO demo_table VALUES (@x + 1);

COMMIT;
```

After the first session commits the transaction, the lock will be lifted, and the query in the second session is returned:

```
+---------+
| MAX(id) |
+---------+
|       4 |
+---------+
1 row in set (8.19 sec)
```

Note that without locking, the second session would have returned immediately, but with `3` as `MAX(id)` instead of `4`. If both sessions were to insert a row with an `id` of `MAX(id) + 1`, both would insert `id = 4`. You can simulate the same test without the `FOR UPDATE` bit to see how this is handled without locks.